# Loading an DLL (write in C++) in C# not working and without error

Tags: c#, dllimport

In my C# program I want to import a DLL written in C/C++. With an little DLL (just 3 function) it's work. But when I want to integrate my entire code it's not working.
More specifically, the DLL loads but does not finish loadin, so I don't call the imported function and my program does not continue. And C# don't take me an error !

I noticed that this behavior happened when in my project I called a proprietary header ("EGrabber.h" from Euresys)

**Update :**

After investigation the problem would be a variable declared in one of my CPP file and whose type is declared in this header.
I started from 0 : I declared and used this variable in an exported function.
Now the DLL is well loaded but when I call this particular function it crashes. I will try to investigate this error.

**Update :**

I solved my problem. I declare my variable in (void *) and I make a new in an exported function. And I can use it fully.

Comment: Include path in the EGrabber.h.  You are running from a different folder and code can't find the header file.

Comment: After investigation the problem would be a variable declared in one of my CPP file and whose type is declared in this header.
I started from 0 : I declared and used this variable in an exported function.
Now the DLL is well loaded but when I call this particular function it crashes. I will try to investigate this error.